# Set multi endpoints in S3 fine uploader for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

The below code works fine for the single endpoint, how to set it for multi endpoints. Please help me.

My requirement is to upload the same file into multiple AWS Buckets.

```js
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
  //debug: true,
  element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-s3'),
  template: 'qq-template-s3',
  request: {
    endpoint: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-bucket',
    accessKey: '123456789'
  },
  signature: {
    endpoint: 's3Upload.php'
  },
  uploadSuccess: {
    endpoint: 's3Upload.php?success'
  },
  iframeSupport: {
    localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
  },
  retry: {
    enableAuto: false // defaults to false
  },
  cors: {
    //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
    expected: true,
    //if you want cookies to be sent along with the request
    sendCredentials: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Upload the file to your server and send it to multiple buckets from there. That is your only option.

Comment: More options http://www.gordonmurray.com/2016/03/14/storing-files-to-multiple-aws-s3-buckets/